# In a MVC 3 Razor view, how to post to different actions, when layout would require forms to be nested?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, nested-forms

Working with some of my MVC 3 Razor views, I find the need to nest forms, which is not possible (not allowed in HTML).

There's one form, targeting a specific action, that contains a table. But on some/all/one_particular tablerow I need to target a separate action. For example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditPersons"))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i=0; i < Model.Persons.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.TextBox(...)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBox(...)</td>
            </tr>
        }
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddPerson")
                    {
                        <input type="submit" value="Add person" />
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Now, I can obviously put the "Add person" button below the entire table, but then how would I get it aligned with the second table column?

Also, I could have the "Add person" button put some "command" in a hidden field, and have the EditPersons action check that to see if it should add a person or save updated data for existing persons, but I feel that would somewhat defeat the paradigm of single purpose actions (as opposed to the horrific old-school ASP "post to itself" forms).

So, how do I solve this?

Comment: Does the "Add Person" button have to submit a form? Can it just be a link? Do you rely on some input values from the user?

Comment: It needs to pass the id of an owner object that users belong to. Omitted from sample code for brevity. The id could be placed in a HTTP-GET query string of course.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I don't see how you need 2 forms and why you need to be using server-side technology.

I'm sure that someone will be able to find a solution using asp.net mvc technology but as far as I'm concerned javascript would do this in a breeze.
So, you want to able to send some values to the server before submitting the whole form or maybe you want parts of a form to work differently and not as a whole. That's fine. Either way javascript is your language, consider these changes to your code (using jQuery):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditPersons"))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i=0; i < Model.Persons.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.TextBox(...)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBox(...)</td>
            </tr>
        }

        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="field" name="field"/></td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btnAddPerson" value="Add person" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="send the whole thing" /></td></tr>

 }
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btnAddPerson").click(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            $.post("/actionTohandle/addperson", { person : $("#field").val()}, function(data){
                //do something with the result
            })
        })
    })
 </script>
```

If you click on the add person button, it will be sending a POST request to the server-side and the FormCollection object will have only one key and that's collection["field"]. The action I'm calling (AddPerson) is on ActionToHandleController. On the other hand if you click on the submit button you'll call the EditPersons on (I'm guessing) PersonsController.
So there you go, 2 different actions on 2 different locations (controllers). Same form.
This example is just the tip of the iceberg. This is one the great features of ASP.NET MVC you have a great deal more of flexibility and not everything has to be handled as server-side scripting.

Comment: It could actually be even simpler: The client-side script could simply add a new table row for a new person. The server would create the new person when the entire form i posted to EditPersons. Possible in this siutation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently doing something similar.  I store in the input element the action to be taken.

```
<input type="submit" value="Add person" data-action"/AddPerson">
```

Then either by subscribing to click or on form submit, change the forms `Action=""` to the data-action by using [.Data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5).

Comment: I was considering that - re-targeting the form using JavaScript. This looks like a rather nice approach in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, it is not legal HTML to place a form tag in a table (that is, wrapping around a tr tag).  It works in some (most?) browsers, but there is no guarantee that it will work, and there's no guarantee that mobile browsers will support it.

So what exactly is the point in asking how you can do something invalid to avoid doing something else that's also invalid?

The correct way to do this is to wrap your table in a form.  Then, you use submit buttons on each row, but you give each one a slightly different id, such as "Submit_1" and then you figure out which row button was clicked by which button is present in the posted values.

Other possibilities is to have JavaScript that will execute when you click the button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="SubmitMyForm(15)" />
```

Where you have a method called SubmitMyForm that takes a parameter for row number (or any other identifier you want to use, perhaps you might use jquery to extract a data attribute value to identify the row).

Finally, at the bottom of your table, you can call a different method, such as "AddPerson" which will modify the action attribute of the form and then call form.submit() and post it to the different action.  Although honestly, in most cases you don't need to post for this.. you can just use a link that redirects to a new page.

In any event, you don't need nested forms (which are invalid) even if wrapping tr's in a form was legal (which it isn't).

Comment: My mistake. I've edited my question, so now the second form in my sample code is now inside the last <TD>. But nested forms are still not allowed so it's still invalid HTML. :-)My question was trying to focus on the problem that I might need an entire table to be placed inside a form, but somehwere inside that table, I'd like to place a button that does something else and needs to post to a different action. The code is just an example to illustrate my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are trying to achieve by this forms... I'd say there should be only one form: edit or create - which one should decide your server (or client) logic. However, if you really need to have two 'nested' forms, you can consider to call actions by using jquery .ajax method